# JSCH Console Read Showing Same Output for Different Commands

Tags: java, ssh, java-8, jsch, cisco

I am trying to send some commands to a router and trying to read the console output. But the problem is every time i send a new command i get the same output. I tried creating a new session after every command is executed but I still get the same output. I got a sample online and modified it according to my needs. When i run it as a standalone class, it works perfectly. But when deployed on a server, it just doesn't seem to work right. To be honest, I am only its only been a day or two I have used the JSCH and documentation is very sparse.

This is how my code reads:

```
private void writeCommand(String command) throws IOException, JSchException {

        Channel channel = getChannel();

        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(command.getBytes());
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setErrStream(System.err);

        readChannelOutput(channel);    
    }

private void readChannelOutput(Channel channel) {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        try {

            InputStream inputStream = channel.getInputStream();

            channel.connect();

            while (true) {

                while (inputStream.available() > 0) {

                    int i = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024);

                    if (i < 0) {
                        break;
                    }

                    deviceOut.updateDeviceOutput(new String(buffer, 0, i));
                }

                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            disconnect();

        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
        }
    }


public Session getSession () throws Exception {

        if (session == null || !session.isConnected()) {
            session = connect(getUserid(), getIpaddress(), getPassword(), getPort());
        }

        return session;
    }


protected Session connect(String userName, String hostname, String password, int port) throws Exception {

        JSch jSch = new JSch();

        try {


            session = jSch.getSession(userName, hostname, port);
            Properties config = new Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword(password);

            logger.debug("Connecting SSH to " + getIpaddress() + " - Please wait for few seconds... ");
            session.connect();
            logger.debug("Connected!");


            if (session.isConnected()) {
                setConnectionState(DeviceConnection.LOGIN_COMPLETE);
            } else {
                setConnectionState(DeviceConnection.LOGIN_FAILED);
                throw new Exception("Failed to login to device");
            }

            deviceOut = new DeviceOutput(getLogger());

            return session;

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            disconnect();
            e.printstacktrace();
        } catch (PalException e) {
            disconnect();
            e.printstacktrace();
        }

    }
```

The commands that I am trying to send are

```
term len 512
```

and

```
show running-config | include hostname
```

But the output just stays the same. The first command should not even have any ouput to be honest. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: *But the output just stays the same.* - what is the output?

Comment: what type channel are you using?

Comment: @Scary Wombat Thanks for the reply. The output always shows "C_{HOSTNAME}_". Hostname being the name of the router. And i am using using channel as "exec".

Comment: Well I was able to get a little bit ahead. I am getting the output i need but it has the weird C_{HOSTNAME}_ appended in the beginning of all outputs.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "*when i run it as a standalone class*" and  "*when deployed on a server*", the difference is important if  the former works and the latter doesn't

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I mean by standalone class, just a basic class with public static void main in it. I wrote one like that to test out the connection and output first. But the main goal is to get the code working in an application running on Websphere.